# Django 1.8 calls to database in html code

Tags: python, html, django

long-time lurker for this website, but I finally decided to join the community.

I have a quick question on some of my code. I took a job this year for my university developing a website for the journalist department. The website was being built the previous year by another student using Django 1.8, python 2, and everything else that comes with that. I knew a decent amount about these languages, and I have learned a lot testing out different methods for hours on end. However, there is one thing I am having trouble with that I have researched for forever.

Basically, for my website, I have different "sections" for different pages of articles. These articles have many traits. One trait is called "section" and this section has the names of the pages. So for example:

One page is named "look". I can call my code and display all of my featured_articles. HOWEVER, I am trying to only display the articles where the name of the section equals "look".

Here is my current code. Any ideas? I have tried many things but I can't get it to work properly. For loops, if statements, different HTML processes, different pages in django, etc...

```
{% for article, section in featured_articles %}
<div class="media panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href="articles/{{ article.url }}">
                <img class="media-object thumbnail-featured"
                     src="{{ article.image }}">
             </a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <a href="articles/{{ article.url }}">
                <h3 class="media-heading">{{ article.title }}</h3>
            </a>


            <!-- TODO figure out how to iterate through the authors field, manytomany -->
            {% for contributor in article.authors.all %}
                <p><a href="/{{ section.url }}">{{ section.name }}</a> |
                   <a href="/contributors/{{ contributor.twitter }}">{{contributor}}</a></p>
            {% endfor %}

            <p>{{article.preview}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: Where is the view function which calls this template? If you want to filter down results where the section matches 'look' It's probably better to do it inside there. If you want to do it inside the template just django's built in conditionals https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#if

Answer (score 1):

Overall, it is a not such a good idea. You are sending all data to the template engine and doing the filtering there?

Why not filter it in the view function / view class and then return that data inside a template variable and then render in the front end?

```
def detail(request, poll_id):       
    filtered_data = .......objects.get(name='look')
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'look_data': filtered_data})

{% for article, section in look_data %}
<div class="media panel panel-default">
    .... blah blah blah
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's what I would like to do eventually. The programmer before me set up the site in a different way, so I am temporarily using Zulfugar's answer below. However, once the website is up, I definitely want to change a few things and use your advice. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you just need to add if statement:

```
{% for article, section in featured_articles %}
{% if section.name == 'look' %}
<div class="media panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href="articles/{{ article.url }}">
                <img class="media-object thumbnail-featured"
                     src="{{ article.image }}">
             </a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <a href="articles/{{ article.url }}">
                <h3 class="media-heading">{{ article.title }}</h3>
            </a>


                <!-- TODO figure out how to iterate through the authors field, manytomany -->
                {% for contributor in article.authors.all %}
                <p><a href="/{{ section.url }}">{{ section.name }}</a> |
                    <a href="/contributors/{{ contributor.twitter }}">{{           contributor }}</a> </p>
                    {% endfor %}

                          <p>{{article.preview}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you!! this is what I need for now. I was trying similar things, but it wasn't clicking for some reason... but this works, so thank you!